# Why enter key takes as input while scanning string in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE for C/C++.
I wrote simple C program to find string length. After scan I'm pressing Enter in console screen but it takes as input and adding one more extra byte in string. It happens only in eclipse IDE in other compiler like online gdb i got accepted output.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LIMIT   127
int main()
{
    char str[MAX_LIMIT];
    int length;
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    fflush(stdout);               // flush the output buffer
    scanf("%[^\n]",str);
    length = strlen(str);
    printf("Length of the string is = %d\n",length);
    return 0;
}
```

Output in Eclipse console screen:

```
Enter the string
hello
Length of the string is = 6
```

Output in other compiler:

```
Enter the string
hello
Length of the string is = 5
```

I tried to solve my self but not getting output

EDIT:

In the comments, I was told to print the individual character codes of the string, by adding the line

```
printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);
```

at the end of my program. When I do this, I get the following output:

```
Enter the string
hello
Length of the string is = 6
68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 00 00
```

Comment: I can't reproduce.  When I run your code and type "hello", it outputs 5, as I would expect.  Are you sure the code you posted is exactly the same as the code you're running?

Comment: *If* you had used `fgets` to read input, it would have retained the `\n` in `str`, and you would have gotten 6.  But `scanf("%[^\n]", …)` does not retain the `\n`.

Comment: Try running in the debugger and inspecting what str[ length - 1 ] is. Or add something like `printf( "Encoded value of last char is is = %d\n", (int)str[ length-1 ] );` Then check what character that encoding represents. (I was also unable to reproduce, but if your post is accurate, that is what I would try.)

Comment: Further to @AviBerger's suggestion, I might go whole-hog and do `printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);`.  I would expect to see `68 65 6c 6c 6f 00 00 00`, where there are clearly 5 (just 5) nonzero character codes visible before the null terminator.  But if you're seeing something else, that should be very interesting.

Comment: In my experience, the Eclipse IDE does some rather strange things. If I had to guess, I would say that the problem is that `str[5]` has the value of the carriage return `'\r'` character. However, the only way to confirm this is for you to perform the test(s) mentioned in the previous two comments.

Comment: If i run thi code in different IDE i got output 5 but this error is only happen in Eclipse IDE

Comment: @TusharMahawar: If you want us to tell you what is going wrong, then you will have to perform the test mentioned above. What happens when you add the line `printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);` immediately before the line `return 0;`? What is the output?

Comment: @TusharMahawar: In your most recent edit, you still have not performed the test that we asked you to do. We need to the see character codes of the string, not just a textual representation of the string. We have provided you with instructions on how to print these character codes. Until you provide this missing information, I'm afraid that your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I performed the test as per you told and i got output like this
```
Enter the string
hello
Length of the string is = 6
68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 00 00

Comment: @TusharMahawar: It appears that my suspicion that I mentioned in a previous comment is correct. `0d` is the character code for the carriage return `'\r'` character. This is vital information that should be in the question itself. Please [edit] the question to add it.

Comment: @TusharMahawar: I have now added this information into the question for you.

Comment: What happens when you add `freopen(NULL, "rt", stdin);` to the start of the program, as the first line inside `main`? Does it then print `5` or `6` as the length of the string?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your Eclipse IDE is not behaving in a way that complies with the ISO C standard.

According to [§7.21.3 ¶7 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p7), standard input must be a text stream, which, according to [§7.21.2 ¶2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p2), must have `\n` line endings. However, according to the information that you provided, it is behaving as a binary stream with `\r\n` line endings.

Therefore, if you want to compensate for this non-compliant behavior of Eclipse, you will have to change the line

```
scanf("%[^\n]",str);
```

to:

```
scanf("%[^\r\n]",str);
```

Comment: For the one `scanf()` in the question, this is sufficient.  If the reading code was embedded in a loop, you'd have to get rid of the newline or carriage return+newline too.  That's fiddlier.  Possibly: `static inline void gobble_eol(void) { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && (c == '\r' || c == '\n')) { if (c == '\n') break; } }` and call `gobble_eol();` after the `scanf()` call.  This reads an arbitrary number of `'\r'` characters and a single `\n'`, or gets EOF.  There's no need for any pushback.  It's harder if you want to handle lines that end with just`'\r'` too (antique MacOS).

Answer (score 0):

**`'\r'` in the stream**

This is an eclipse interface, compiler and keyboard issue.  The keyboard <kbd>Enter</kbd> injects both <kbd>Ctrl R</kbd> and   <kbd>Ctrl N</kbd> and *gcc's* `stdin` blindly takes this in as a common character the <kbd>Ctrl R</kbd> followed by an <kbd>end-of-line</kbd>.  If you cut/paste sequence like `"123\n"` from some other source into the console window (or pipe data in from the command line), code will work as expected.

This is not a case of text vs. binary stream issue.  Note: `stdout` prints without a `'\r'`.

**Issue: buffer overrun**

Do not code `scanf("%[^\n]",str);` (or `scanf("%[^\r\n]",str);` (to ignore the`'\r'`) without a *width*.

Do not use `str` afterword without checking the return value.

```
if (scanf("%126[^\r\n]",str) != 1) {
  Handle_error();
}
```

**Alternate**

Read a *line* of input with `fgets()`.

```
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_error();
}
// Lop off line endings
str[strcspn(str, "\r\n")] = '\0';
```

Note that this 2nd version nicely reads a *line* of only `"\n"`, whereas the `scanf("%[^\n]", ...)` does not.

Also `scanf("%[^\r\n]",str)` still leaves those pesky `"\r\n"` to be read by *something*.

---

**Deeper**

In a way the incoming of `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` on `stdin` allows one to consider how to make an executable resilient to  being run is various environments.  I have found that a set of re-directed input from a file may have originated in with the `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` land and strive to make code handle either.  Steps include :

- Do not use a simplistic `scanf()` to read a *line* of input.  It is not the right tool.  `fgets()` is better.
- Use `str[strcspn(str, "\r\n")] = '\0';` to end the line of text either way.
- Increase the size of  `str[]` by 1.